# How can I return cv::Mat with data from a independent function

Tags: opencv

here is a funtion like this:

```
cv::Mat func(const std::string& path) {
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    int n_col = img.cols;
    int n_row = img.rows;
    img.convertTo(result, CV_32F);
    float* data_in = (float*)img.data;

    do some computation...

    cv::Mat result = cv::Mat(n_row, n_col, CV_32FC1, data_in);
    return result;
}
```

the main function:

```
int main(){
    ...
    cv::Mat result = func(path);
    cv::imwrite("result.bmp", result);
    ...
}
```

when this code run into
`cv::imwrite("result.bmp", result);`,it will catch exceptions. I use vs2013 to view the result return from the `func`, it's not empty and has the same dimensions as `img`.

**Can anyone help me identify where I am going wrong?**

**Is there any beter way to realize the funtion `cv::Mat func(const std::string& path)`?**

**ANSWER:** 
Change`cv::Mat result = cv::Mat(n_row, n_col, CV_32FC1, data_in);` into `cv::Mat result = cv::Mat(n_row, n_col, CV_32FC1, data_in).clone();` **works** !

**Explaination:** 
When I construct Mat with `float* data_in` , OpenCV just initialize the matrix header that points to the specified data, which means that **no data is copied**.

The external data is not automatically deallocated, but is destroyed when the `func` ends. That will catch exception.

Comment: cv::Mat result = cv::Mat(n_row, n_col, CV_32FC1, data_in).clone();

Comment: your data array is too small to represent n_row*n_col CV_32FC1 values, because the image you've read from file is CV_8UC1. So your image is broken. use .convertTo to change the type.

Comment: Actually, I did convert the img to CV_32FC1 before(`img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);`), I think **Miki**'s answer is right. Thx!

Comment: Looking at `func(...)`, `result` seems quite redundant right now. You've used `data_in` to modify the contents of `img`, so just return `img` after the "do some computation", and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cv::Mat func(const std::string& path)
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(path,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

do some computation...

    cv::Mat result;
    img.convertTo(result, CV_32F);

    return result;
}
```

If you want to deep-copy wn image, use .clone() or .copyTo()